# read/write function definiton

Tags: function, readability

how would you write these functions:

```
bool writesomething(const Something& something);
//or
bool writesomething(int somethingid, const Something& something);

bool readsomething(const Something& something);
//or
bool readsomething(int somethingid, Something& something);
```

notice that *Something* has a public field named *id*

Comment: I would avoid the second form.  Passing the id and the object is redundant -- and what would happen if somethingId != something.id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the structure of Something.  But as a general design principle, your classes should be persistence ignorant when possible.

That being said, if you want to be able to (de)serialize your objects, I would model your I/O methods on the built-in I/O streams library interfaces.  Then your objects will support I/O to/from the console, files, anything else that inherits from `istream` or `ostream`.

In addition to maintaining a consistent interface with the standard library (and tons of third-party-code), adapting the I/O streams interface also makes it easier to write your method.  If Something has an int 'id' and a string 'name' member:

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Something& thing)
{
    os << thing.id;
    os << thing.name;
    return os;
}
```

If the members of Something are more complex you implement operator << and >> for those types, and so on down the chain.

Comment: I think it's better to avoid the separated id param when reading (deserializing) and i suppose it's all right to use the Something.id in the write function (serializing). What do you think?

Comment: Again, since the object already contains the id, IMO it's redundant.  Now if you have the objects in a map<int, Something>, so you can pass _only_ the ID, that's a different story.

Let's rephrase the question.  Which value would you actually persist, the id parameter or the id member off the object?  If the former, maybe you don't want to store the id on the object; if the latter, then the id as a param is redundant (and a potential source of errors).

Comment: Sorry, i missed your comment on the question ^^ They should be equal, so i will send only the object reference. Thanks for your thoughts.